# How to save the information of a form so that it appears in the Admin Site Panel?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am making a web page and there is a contact section in which I am looking for people to leave a message and then I contact them, I want the information entered in the form to be stored in the database so that later I can see it in the Django Admin Page.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Nombre")
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Email")
    issue = models.CharField(max_length = 200, verbose_name = "Asunto")
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name = "Mensaje")


# forms.py
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, label = "Nombre")
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Correo electrónico")
    issue = forms.CharField(max_length = 200, label = "Asunto")
    text = forms.CharField(label = "Mensaje")


# views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from contact.forms import ContactForm
from django.shortcuts import render

class Contact(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contact/contact.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = ContactForm
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            issue = form.cleaned_data['issue']
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            form = ContactForm()
            args = {
                'form': form, 
                'name': name,
                'email': email,
                'issue': issue,
                'text': text,
                }

            return render(request, self.template_name, args)


<!-- And this is the form -->
<div class="page-section contact-page">
    <div class="contact-warp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6 p-0">
                <div class="contact-text">
                    <span>¡Hola!</span>
                    <h2>Contáctame</h2>
                    <form class="contact-form" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button class="site-btn">Enviar mensaje</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have made several attempts but I can not get the information to appear in the admin, (I have already registered the model in the admin). 
Please, help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you are not using **ModelForm**, then you need to save those values manually in the View. Like this:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        issue = form.cleaned_data['issue']
        text = form.cleaned_data['text']
        args = {
            'form': form, 
            'name': name,
            'email': email,
            'issue': issue,
            'text': text,
        }
        Contact.objects.create(**args)  # <-- saving to DB
        # rest of the code
```

I am not sure why you are using TemplateView, because [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) is much more appropriate for handling form. For example:

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'contact/contact.html'
    success_url= '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        issue = form.cleaned_data['issue']
        text = form.cleaned_data['text']
        args = {
            'form': form, 
            'name': name,
            'email': email,
            'issue': issue,
            'text': text,
        }
        Contact.objects.create(**args)
        return super(ContactView).form_valid(form)
```

Also, if you use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), then you can simply store data like this:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = "__all__"

# usage

if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    # rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `form.save()` so your data gets saved. It's not being saved currently. Call it inside `form.is_valid():` block.

Also, you don't need to pass the form values. You can access them using `form.data.field_name`.